# jQuery check for existence of input after remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a form where a user is supposed to select predefined data add new data in an input field named `xxx` and then he/she can proceed further.

When predefined data is selected, a new hidden input is created

`$('.selectlists').append('<input type="hidden" name="select" value="1"  />')`

I have a function which checks if the hidden field exists and if input `xxx` has any value

```
function checkAll(){
        if( $("input[name*='select']") ){
            alert('ok');
        }
        else{
            if ( $("input[name*='xxx']").val() != '') {
                alert('ok');
            }
        }
    }
```

The function is working fine. But if I create the hidden input and then remove it with jQuery's function `remove()`, my function `checkAll()` is showing that the hidden input still exists.

Comment: How about  if( $("input[name='select']").length)

Comment: OK, that is definitely the solution of my problem. I'm still wondering why is this function showing the existance of an input.

Comment: $('...') never returns null or undefined, it returns an empty array if nothing is ound. So your condition will always be true if you don't check the length.

Comment: ("input[name*='select']") or ("input[name='select']") both returns an array. So even if there is no element this will return an empty array.Therefore we have to check the length of the array. Hope you understand. My English is not that good..

Comment: But funny thing is that the function works untill the `select` input is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($("input[name*='select']")) ...
```

should check for the length ...

```
if( $("input[name*='select']").length > 0)
```

JQuery returns an array of matching elements.

Answer (score 1):

you create input like

`$('.selectlists').append('<input type="hidden" name="select" value="1" />')`.

Right ?

```
$('.selectlists input[name="select"]').remove();
```

**try** in `checkAll` method:

```
if( $(".selectlists input[name='select']") ){
            alert('ok');
        }
```

or

```
if( $(".selectlists input[name='select']").length ){
            alert('ok');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `length` property for testing if some element exists, because the function `$()` returns an array of objects and in javascript all arrays evaluates to true, even if they are empty, which is the case.

```
if( $("input[name*='select']").length ){
     alert('ok');
}
```

This way, if there's no `input[name*='select']` the length will be zero and the expression will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your check will show an alert box with 'ok', when the input field is not present because

```
$("input[name*='xxx']").val()
```

Will return 'undefined' and not match empty string.

You can check for the existence of elements by checking if the jQuery object return any hits OR check for 'undefined'

Either of these should work:

```
typeof $('input[name=xxx]').val() === 'undefined'
```

or

```
$('input[name=xxx]').length === 0
```

I would prefer option 2. because it seems more robust to changes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isexists(){
   var hiddenLen = $(".selectlists input[name*='select']:hidden").length,
       hasval = $.trim( $("input[name*='xxx']").val() ).length;
   return {
      hiddedexists: !len,
      hasval : !hasval
    };
}
```

You can use this function like:

```
var exists = isexists();

exists.hiddenexists; // true of false
exists.hasval;  // true of false
```

#### Note

`!len` will give `true` if `len=0` else `false`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 if( jQuery("*[name='select']") ){
            alert('ok');
        }
```